# How can i put php array in javascript

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to fetch php array in javascript

```
<script>
    var start = ["<?php echo $starta; ?>"];
    var startab = ["<?php echo $startb; ?>"];
    var rows = ["<?php echo $rows; ?>"];
    var i = 0;
```

display the array:

```
    var data = { values:[{
      for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
          X: start[i], Y: startab
     }},
    ]};
</script>
```

Comment: Replace `var start = ["<?php echo $starta; ?>"];` with `var start = <?php echo json_encode($starta); ?>;` same for other `startab`

Comment: @AmitGarg i think my error is in the for loop.. i can separate the array in php

Answer (score 0):

try with -

```
var start = ["<?php echo implode(',', $starta); ?>"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing a straight json_encode, it's faster and will iterate the entire array correctly.

```
var start = <?=json_encode($start)?>
```

Comment: i think my error is in the for loop.. i can separate the array in php